# Siebel Dynamic Button

Tags: crm, siebel

The button in the form applet should have two different names one before pressing the button and one after pressing the button.( **Send OTP** and after sending it Should change to **Verify OTP**).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned which version of Siebel you are using. Your requirement seems to be to change the text on the button control dynamically. Couple of ways to do this. If you are on OpenUI, you can use jQuery to easily change button captions. You will have to write a PM to bind to the InvokeMethod method. This code will be outside the repository.

If you are on high interactivity, you can achieve this via browser script. There are browserscript functions [FindControl](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/OIRef/OIRefInterfaceRef178.html) with which you can change control attributes. This code will go into applet browserscripts, and you need to run genbscipt after compilation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answer, You can also achieve this with Toggle applet as well.

Steps:

1. Create Toggle applet copying the main applet.Set a flag when Send OTP is successfully submitted from main applet.
2. Toggle Applet will be displayed now when flag is set. Update the button name to Verify OTP in the Toggle Applet.

For an ideal situation, I would suggest a design change in this requirement. Create 2 buttons Send OTP and Verify OTP in the form applet. Button enable disable logic as per business requirement. I have a similar requirement in my project for Verifying Finger Print.